# Login popup vs Login page

Tags: c#, html, authentication

want to know what is the best practice when you have multiple logins forms.

Do you:
A) Place each on a single webform.
B) Use modal popup with update panel inside.

Trying to think which is best for SEO.

Cheers

Comment: Umm. Why are you trying to SEO a login form?!

Comment: any way i recommend using jquery instead of modal popup (asumming you're talking about the modal popup from ajax control toolkit)

Answer (score 2):

Do whichever creates the better user experience. If you are worried about SEO on your login pages, you may want to reconsider your priorities.